# Cross-domain images behavior of IE vs Chrome?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, cross-domain, easeljs, createjs

I am using TypeScript, EaselJs/CreateJs and IIS Express to write a small sample app. However, when I try to add a "click" event to a Bitmap object, I keep getting the following error: JavaScript runtime error: An error has occurred. This is most likely due to security restrictions on reading canvas pixel data with local or cross-domain images.". That error happens only in Internet Explorer and not Chrome.

My HTML and SVG image (Bitmap object source) live on the same local server (IISExpress). Why am I getting cross-domain error? Why the two browsers don't behave the same way for cross-domain images? How do I fix this so that Internet Explore allows me to click on the image (I'd like to not interested in disabling security options).

Thanks!

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="http://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="1496" height="1024"></canvas>

    <script>
        var stage = new createjs.Stage(document.getElementById('gameCanvas'));

        var svgImage = new createjs.Bitmap("SvgFile.svg");
        svgImage.on("click", sayHi);
        stage.addChild(svgImage);

        createjs.Ticker.setFPS(40);
        createjs.Ticker.on("tick", tick);

        function sayHi() {
            alert("Hello!"); // INTERNET EXPLORER CRASHES. CHROME DISPLAYS "Hello!".
        }

        function tick() {
            stage.update();
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**svgfile.svg**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="467" height="462">
  <rect x="80" y="60" width="250" height="250" rx="20"
      style="fill:#ff0000; stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2px;" />

  <rect x="140" y="120" width="250" height="250" rx="40"
      style="fill:#0000ff; stroke:#000000; stroke-width:2px;
      fill-opacity:0.7;" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Easeljs Bitmap Class Documentation:](http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Bitmap.html)

> Bitmaps with an SVG source will taint the canvas with cross-origin
>   data, which prevents interactivity. This happens in all browsers
>   except recent Firefox builds.

There was also an [issue on Github](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues/334) which has been closed:

> Unfortunately SVG always throws cross-origin errors in browsers other
>   than Firefox. This is a bug in the canvas implementation. EaselJS
>   requires pixel access to do mouse interaction, which is why that
>   happens.